# 'ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

Tags: python, django

I'm moving my web application to **Django 1.7** and I have a very curious mistake, perhaps one of you know is happening.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_lenght=100)
    slug = models.SlugField()
    content = models.TextField()

class Gallery(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="images")
    original = models.ImageField()

class MyView(DetailView):
    model = Product

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       ....
       # My error is here, when use this context and parse template
       context["galleries"] = Product.images.all()
```

Givin the following error message:

```
'ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try:

```
context["galleries"] = self.object.images.all()
```

You'll want to call it on a specific instance of your `Product` model, which should be your object.